Bind9: Best way to manage single zones between multiple views?
I have a fairly overcomplicated Bind9 DNS ecosystem which has worked for many years.  I have about 20 zones, and they're split among 2 views (the only difference between the 2 views is the forwarder; one upstreams to filtered DNS, the other does not).  Because the zones have historically been read-only (I manually manage the zone files) this has been fine.  Because the zones are referenced in both views but are read only, I can point both zones to a single file and do updates in a single file.  This is what I want; common internal DNS records available to all classes of client no matter the view.
I'm now trying to enable SSHFP, which requires DNSSEC.  In enabling that (per this guide: https://bind9.readthedocs.io/en/v9.18.14/dnssec-guide.html#easy-start-guide-for-signing-authoritative-zones ), I've learned that the zone files become writeable and thus bind errors out because writeable zone files cannot exist in multiple zones; best practice says copy the zone files to make them unique per view.  This would double the effort in my manual process, which I don't want to do.  I've read through this as well: https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00295
I've been through the documents, but I don't see a way to manage this efficiently.  It's not like I can have an "all" view and a "filtered" view and an "unfiltered" view, with clients matching "all" and their specific view because view matching is singular and stops after a hit.  Using includes doesn't work either; it'll trigger the same error about writeable zone files being in multiple views.
So the questions are:

Is there a better way to do this without views?  Is there a way to designate a forwarder based on the client acl list?  That's how I'm doing my view matching.
How bad of an idea would it be to just linux hack this; symlink the zone files from the "unfiltered" zone folder to the "filtered" zone folder?  I think this would break as the 2 zone definitions would fight over updating keys.
Is there another way to define a zone in multiple views that doesn't include maintaining 2 manual zone files?  I've seen example 4 here, but it's certainly maintaining 2 zone files: https://kb.isc.org/docs/aa-00851
Am I totally off based and I should be thinking of it a different way?


I believe the answer here is the best answer; it involves making 3 directories in my zone directory (internal-default, internal-filtered, internal-common) then using an $INCLUDE statement in the default/filtered pointing to the common one:  bind9 - one domain for multiple zones
